Unity C# - Check for overflow text in a text box. If so remove it and move it into the beginning of a string list
I'm making a typing game that pulls lines from a text file, adds them to a string array and displays as many as it can fit in a text box. When all lines that currently fit are typed, they are removed from the list and the text box and replaced with the next set of lines that can fit. The text box right now will add lines to the text box until a line would be added that would make the text overflow. Since some lines are longer than the entire length of the text box I want the system to remove only the text that would overflow, not the entire line.
My entire script for the game is listed below. Right now the script tries to add lines to the text box but if the line would cause overflow it does not add the line and stops trying to add more until the Update Text Display is called again. I tried many ways to find all the text that overflows and somehow put it in a new string to be added next in line in the allLines list but after hours I have given up. I would really appreciate help in making it so that any text that would cause overflow is not displayed but the rest of the line that can fit still would. Also the lines in the text file cannot be modified so if some are too long there's no way I can change this.
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TypingGameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference to the TextMeshProUGUI component
    public TextMeshProUGUI textMeshPro;

    // Name of the text file in the Resources folder (without extension)
    public string fileName = "YourTextFile";

    // Color for typed characters
    public Color32 typedColor = new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255); // Green color

    public List<string> allLines;
    public int currentLineIndex = 0;
    public int currentCharIndex = 0;
    public int linesDisplayed = 0;
    public int linesShown;

    // Typewriter audio components
    public AudioClip typingSound;
    public AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        // Load the text asset from the Resources folder
        TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(fileName);

        // Check if the text asset was found
        if (textAsset != null)
        {
            // Split the text into lines
            allLines = new List<string>(textAsset.text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

            // Set TextMeshPro overflow mode to truncate
            textMeshPro.overflowMode = TextOverflowModes.Truncate;

            // Display the first batch of lines in the TextMeshPro component
            UpdateTextDisplay();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("File not found in Resources: " + fileName);
        }

        // Set the typing sound
        audioSource.clip = typingSound;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (currentLineIndex < allLines.Count)
        {
            if (currentCharIndex < allLines[currentLineIndex].Length)
            {
                // Check if a key was pressed
                if (Input.anyKeyDown)
                {
                    // Get the pressed key
                    string input = Input.inputString;
                    if (input.Length > 0)
                    {
                        char typedChar = input[0];
                        // Check if the typed character matches the current character in the line
                        if (typedChar == allLines[currentLineIndex][currentCharIndex])
                        {
                            audioSource.Play();
                            // Move to the next character
                            currentCharIndex++;
                            // Update the display
                            UpdateTextDisplay();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Move to the next line or refill if all characters in the current lines have been typed
                if (currentLineIndex + 1 < allLines.Count)
                {
                    currentLineIndex++;
                    currentCharIndex = 0;
                    UpdateTextDisplay();
                }
                if (currentLineIndex == linesShown)
                {
                    // If all lines have been typed, refill the text box with new lines
                    RefillTextBox();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateTextDisplay()
    {
        // Combine all lines into a single string with typed characters colored
        string displayedText = "";
        string testText = "";
        linesShown = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i >= linesDisplayed)
            {
                if (i == currentLineIndex)
                {
                    // Separate the typed part and the remaining part of the current line
                    string typedText = allLines[i].Substring(0, currentCharIndex);
                    string remainingText = allLines[i].Substring(currentCharIndex);

                    // Create a colored string for the typed part
                    string coloredTypedText = $"<color=#{ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(typedColor)}>{typedText}</color>";

                    // Append the current line with colored typed text
                    testText += coloredTypedText + remainingText;
                }
                else if (i < currentLineIndex)
                {
                    // Previous lines, fully typed
                    testText += $"<color=#{ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(typedColor)}>{allLines[i]}</color>";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Future lines, not yet typed
                    testText += allLines[i];
                }

                // Add a newline character between lines
                if (i < allLines.Count - 1)
                {
                    testText += "\n";
                }

                // Temporarily set text to calculate height
                textMeshPro.text = testText;
                textMeshPro.ForceMeshUpdate();

                // Check if text overflows
                if (textMeshPro.isTextOverflowing)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    displayedText = testText;
                    linesShown++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Update the TextMeshPro text
        textMeshPro.text = displayedText;
    }

    void RefillTextBox()
    {
        Debug.Log("To Refill");
        // Clear the current text
        textMeshPro.text = "";

        // Reset line and character indices
        currentLineIndex = 0;
        currentCharIndex = 0;
        // linesDisplayed = 0;

        // Remove typed lines from the list
        allLines.RemoveRange(0, linesShown);

        // Display the next batch of lines in the TextMeshPro component
        UpdateTextDisplay();
    }
}


you could work on a simple principle, of say you decide to allow 15 lines of text, now, some lines willbe 2 lines, but you leave only the 15 lines and dont allow scrollback, so the new text is visible, and any spare is ignored, and at worst theres a few spare lines not shown you havent recycled yet

The property isTextOverflowing internally just checks for

  public bool isTextOverflowing
  {
      get { if (m_firstOverflowCharacterIndex != -1) return true; return false; 
  }


which is also available public so you can just take the firstOverflowCharacterIndex and use it to extract the Substring which is overflowing and can then push it to the next update
if(textMeshPro.isTextOverflowing)
{
    var firstOverlowCharIndex = textMeshPro.firstOverflowCharacterIndex;
    var fittingText = testText.Substring(0, firstOverlowCharIndex)
    var overflowingText = testText.Substring(firstOverlowCharIndex);
    
    textMeshPro.text = fittingText;

    // TODO: do something with the overflowingText - e.g. chain it back to the list etc
}

